# Why Custom Date field displays Year value till 2021?

Tags: date, configuration

I have created a field "Test Date" of type date on opportunity object.
On Opportunity Record when I want to provide date value(year) as 2022 or 2023,it displays list of years till 2021.

Scenario:when user selects start date as 2017 and if the contract is 5 years then the end date should be 2022 but in calendar it displays till 2021.

Can someone please suggest why it shows years till 2021?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't use the picklist for years beyond 2021. However, you can just type in any year beyond that and it will work. (I just tried it with 2055.)

Comment: @Kasper Is there not any other option(Apex or Configuration) other than manually typing year value?

Comment: We can also try another option.Select the date December 2021 click next to it,it will show you year as 2022. I have found an interesting article https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003739&type=1              where if we want to select a year the it display only past year,present year and 5 years from now and this is the standard functionality :(

Answer (score 0):

We can also try another option.Select the date December 2021 click next to it,it will show you year as 2022. I have found an interesting article [help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003739&type=1](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003739&type=1)                           where if we want to select a year the it display only past year,present year and 5 years from now and this is the standard functionality :(